# Div Tags Don't Contain Elements?

Tags: html, css

Perhaps someone can help me as I cannot even see straight anymore. I have tried everything I can find here, and in other forums to no avail. I have set up some divs to put inside a main container for a site I am building. The content inside the divs keeps going outside the divs and I cannot figure out why. I have published the page, with the css attached to the head, here:
http://210usa.com/menu_test.html
I have placed different background colors, ugly ones, for illustration purposes only. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You:-)

Comment: Please post some relevant CSS & markup here - not everyone is willing to go visit some random site to see what you're doing...

Comment: Sorry, I will next time, I just didn't want to put so much code here.

Comment: @210USA: If it helped, please mark my answer as the 'accepted answer'. [More info here...](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because of the float:left that you use, you have to put some clear fix, for example setting container's overflow to hidden

Comment: Or should I say, dziekuje bardzo Pawel?

Comment: Pawel, mam pytanie. I have a script for Google driving directions and I am using Bootstrap 2.2. All elements within the wrappers resize for responsive behavior, however the script does not. It goes outside of the wrapper. I can set the overflow to hidden but it cuts the script short. Is there a way to make the script responsive and resize within the wrapper? You can see it here: http://angrybullhartford.com/index.php/events/
I have the middle map in the footer set to overflow:hidden.
Jeszcze raz dziękuję. Miłego dnia.

Comment: I don't see any map on the attached link :)

Comment: Tak, wiem. by the time you looked at it I already had another site meltdown and had to basically start from scratch. It is there now. I am still working on the rest of the site. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the overflow attribute to all those divs as below, should help:

```
.menuApps, .menuGrinders, .menuPizza, .menuDinner {
    overflow: auto;
}
```